# Iterative-substitution method yields different solution for T(n)=3T(n/8)+n than expected by using master theorem

Tags: runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

I's like to guess the running time of recurrence $T(n)=3T(n/8)+n$ using iterative-substitution method. Using master theorem, I can verify the running time is $O(n).$ Using subtitution method however, I arrive at a different answer than expected..

$T(n)=3T(n/8)+n\\
=3T(3T(n/8^2)+n)+n=3^2T(n/8^2)+3n+n\\
=3^2(3T(n/8^3)+n)+3n+n=3^3T(n/8^3)+3^2n+3n+n$

We can see the pattern: $3^iT(n/8^i)+n*\frac{3^i -1}{2}$

The recursion finishes when $i=log_8 n$.

Substituting i into the discovered pattern,
 $3^{log_8 n}T(1)+n*\frac{3^{log_8 n} -1}{2} =\\ n^{log_8 3}*c+0.5n*n^{log_8 3} - 0.5n =n^{log_8 3}*c+ 0.5n^{log_8 3+1}-0.5n \in O(n^{1.52})$.

What am I doing wrong? why is my answer not $O(n)$ ?

Comment: Looks like your first substitution isn't correct. $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{8}) + n = 3 \left( 3T(\frac{n}{8^{2}}) + \color{blue}{\frac{n}{8}}\right) = \dots$

Comment: Thanks ! @Elman